# How to get list of price From DynamoDb

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

[image: this is my data in my database same time and same symbol can have list of price]

my question is how to get list of data from my database using search if i have 2 condition use symbol and time ? because it is my first time to use search item using DynamoDb. i have update my dynamodb my primary key is symbol and sortKey is priceId

my propose is how to get list of Price if i have condition symbol and time using dynamoDB

Comment: What's the primary key of your table?

Comment: my primary key is priceId and my sort key is symbol. so symbol is one of primary key here

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to run the query you requested on the current table design. `Query` in dynamodb can only condition on sort key, not all attributes in an item. Therefore, if the query

> get list of price if i have condition symbol and time

is your primary access pattern, I suggest you making `symbol` as partition key and `Time` as sort key.

Comment: ohh i see i will change it thanks for your advice @jellycsc